# Why does adding axes to a subgridspec mess with <wspace> parameter?

Tags: matplotlib, subplot, subgrid, matplotlib-gridspec

I have a grid with 4 subplots and 2 overlaying subplots to create common xlabels between the first two and last two subplots (see code below). I get a slightly different spacing between the 2 subplots on the left compared to the two subplots on the right even though  parameters are set to equal values, why?

If no overlaying axes are added, then the spacing is as expected. Below also a link with the image example.

[Result of below code and example of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgLec.png)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
# make the grid
fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True, figsize=(8,3))
grsp = GridSpec(1,4, figure=fig, wspace=0.6, width_ratios=[1,0.05,1,0.05])

grsp_one = grsp[0,0].subgridspec(1,2, wspace=0.01)
grsp_two = grsp[0,2].subgridspec(1,2, wspace=0.01)

axs_one = grsp_one.subplots(sharey='row')
axs_two = grsp_two.subplots(sharey='row')
# create the ovelapping ax on selection of axes
axmaster_1 = fig.add_subplot(grsp_one[0,0:2])
axmaster_2 = fig.add_subplot(grsp_two[0,0:2])

for axmaster in [axmaster_1, axmaster_2]:
    # hide the ticks of the master axis
    axmaster.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.NullLocator())
    axmaster.yaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.NullLocator())
    axmaster.spines[['bottom', 'right', 'top', 'left']].set_visible(False)
    axmaster.set_zorder(-10)


axmaster_1.set_xlabel('xlabel_1', labelpad=20)
axmaster_2.set_xlabel('xlabel_2', labelpad=20)

axmaster_1.set_ylabel('ylabel_1', labelpad=30)
axmaster_2.set_ylabel('ylabel_2', labelpad=30)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I think it comes from setting `constrained_layout=True`, which will play around with the spacings when the plot is created. But I'm afraid I'm not sure what exactly it will be doing in this case and why you see a difference when overlaying axes are added or not.

Comment: @MattPitkin thanks a lot. As suggested I set `constrained_layout=False` and got the same result. Unfortunately it did not solve the issue.

Comment: Hmmm, if I set `constrained_layout=False`, and increase `wspace` for `grsp_one` and `grsp_two` to, e.g., 0.4, then it comes out with consistent spacings for me. There may be differences between matploltib versions. I'm using v3.6.3.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @MattPitkin, setting `constrained_layout=False` with updated matplotlib version solves the issue of unequal spaces but requires some fiddling with `wspace, hspace, left, bottom, right, top` of the gridspec and subgridspec to make the figure good looking.